# Concurrency in Dart and Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I’m having some interesting behavior in the Polymer components of my web app, with the timing of how the views are entered. My primary question is, how does the concurrency all work with Polymer, between the observables and inbound messages with web sockets? Is there a tutorial or other documentation on how all that works?

A little background: I currently have my app open a web socket to somewhere, which will get notification events. I also have a separate HTTP request that will trigger a series of messages on the web socket, distributed in time. These events get deserialized into VOs and sent through a notification callback scheme. Then endpoint of this notification scheme is that a List gets bound to an observable in a parent Polymer element (e.g. table), which runs through the list, and create child polymer elements (e.g. tableentry). There is a peripheral Polymer element (growl), that isn’t connected to the other polymer elements, yet is still on the notification channel.

When the initial messages come in, the notifications are triggered just fine, and presumably the objects are bound in. However the tableentry views are never entered. The table view is entered at the start of the application, as well as the growl. It isn’t until a notification on the growl changes a bound list on it, that any of the tableentry views are entered.

So is there something with observables and polymer that, unless an observable list is modified, not just re-bound to a different list, that some event handler thread isn’t started? Is there a way to start that up explicitly?

Thanks,

-Dirv

Comment: What does "VOs" stand for?